# Image download from Google Shopping tab using BeautifulSoup

Tags: python, beautifulsoup

I want to download images from **Google Shopping** tab using BeautifulSoup. However, `<img>` element from this page contains `src` attribute with following format.

```
data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==
```

And every `<img>` element throughout the page has the same value for `src` attribute.

This is different from **Google Images** in which proper image URL is present.

How can I download these images?
Another way is to open these Shopping website URLs and download image but that won't give me guarantee that the same image will get downloaded.

Answer (score 1):

What you see is a `base64` encoding for an image, which is the standard way of transferring images on the web (read more [here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Base64)).

The characters which follow the `data:image/gif;base64,` prefix are actually the image itself, it just needs a decoding. Try the code below and see if it decodes the image successfully.

```py
import base64

# assume `src` is the scraped src from the <img> tag

img_encoded = src.split(',')[1]             # extract the encoding
img_decoded = base64.b64decode(img_encoded) # decode
with open('file.gif', 'wb') as f:         
    f.write(img_decoded)                    # write the file as a .gif
```

Try opening `file.gif` and check whether the image has been successfully decoded.

Comment: Yes. I had read about it. However, this string is very small and the same string is present for every image across the page. How should I make sense of it? I am really confused.

Comment: I have looked into Google Shopping images and I've been able to decode one of them successfully.

What I suggest is to first try it by copy-pasting the b64 encoding from your browser to a `python` script and making sure the code runs as expected.
Then try to compare the length of the copy-pasted b64 encoding with the length of the scraped b64 encoding. If they're not roughly the same size then it may be that Google is giving you a placeholder image and the actual image may be loaded by a JS script.

Comment: So did you use the data from src attribute or took it from JS Script "var s="?

Comment: When testing I just copy pasted the `src` attribute from the `<img>` tag. That `src` may not be available by simply making a plain `GET` request since it could be loaded later by a JS script

Answer (score 0):

Finally I found the missing piece. (Experts in this area, please correct my assumptions if it doesn't make sense)

I could see following `img` element for each image.

```
<img alt="" class="TL92Hc" data-deferred="1" id="srpresultimg_13038633776657256825_1_0" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhAQABAIAAAP///////yH5BAEKAAEALAAAAAABAAEAAAICTAEAOw==" style="height:180px;width:153px" />
```

Here, there is an attribute named `data-deferred` which is set to "1". So, I thought that I needed to search for `id` attribute of this `img` element somewhere else in the page. And then I found a Javascript code which linked this id with the image contents as follows -

```
<script nonce="OnanMpQNnve2s3LIbFHDqQ==">
                (function() {
                    var s = <huge_image_data_string>;
var ii = ['srpresultimg_13038633776657256825_1_0'];
                    _setImagesSrc(ii, s);
                })();
```

This *<huge_image_data_string>* part is the data I was looking for.